# Why do I still get a warning about a memory leak after canceling a subscription

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am getting:

```
react-dom.development.js:91 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in ProductBookingForm (at Product.js:482)
    in div (at Product.js:476)
    in div (at Product.js:443)
    in div (at Product.js:434)
    in div (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Media (at Product.js:785)
    in ResponsiveProvider (created by MediaContextProvider)
    in MediaContextProvider (at Product.js:784)
```

I have one useEffect calling an api call in the component `ProductBookingForm`

I have used the cleanup function as follows;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    if (currentAvailabilities.first_date == undefined) {
      reloadOnce().then((response) => {
        if (mounted) {
          dispatch(setAvailabilities(response.data.currentAvailabilities));
          setSelectedDate(response.data.currentAvailabilities.current_time);
        }
      });
    }

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Why could I be still getting this warning?

Comment: Are you *sure* this is the code causing the issue? I am unable to reproduce the warning both in React 18 and in [React 17](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-do-i-still-get-a-warning-about-a-memory-leak-after-canceling-a-subscription-eozj8p). Can you edit your post to provide a more complete code example? Could you try also creating a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the warning that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: The warning was removed in react 18 - https://medium.com/doctolib/react-stop-checking-if-your-component-is-mounted-3bb2568a4934

Answer (score 1):

Put your **IF CONDITIONS** inside your **NATIVE FUNCTION**

Also if you are doing more than one chaining in an object, most especially in a useEffect  you are to use

**OPTIONAL CHAINING (?.)** example: **response.data?.currentAvailabilities**

OR

**TRUTHY CONDITION** example **response.data && response.data.currentAvailabilities**

now apply this in your useEffect like these **BELOW**

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    reloadOnce().then((response) => {
      if (currentAvailabilities.first_date == undefined && mounted) {
        dispatch(setAvailabilities(response.data?.currentAvailabilities));
        setSelectedDate(response.data?.currentAvailabilities?.current_time);
       
          }
      });
    

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

**OR**

```
useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;

    reloadOnce().then((response) => {
     if (currentAvailabilities.first_date == undefined) {
       if (mounted) {
        dispatch(setAvailabilities(response.data?.currentAvailabilities));
        setSelectedDate(response.data?.currentAvailabilities?.current_time);
       }
     }
    });
    

    return () => {
      mounted = false;
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I have applied it, but it keeps triggering this warning, the warning points me to the code in this useEffect, still

Comment: ok, now try and put your IF CONDITIONS: ```if (currentAvailabilities.first_date == undefined) { //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true }``` inside your your reloadOnce function, for example ```reloadOnce().then((response) => { if (currentAvailabilities.first_date == undefined) {  //  block of code to be executed if the condition is true
}}```, i think that's the reason for your memory leak, i really have faced this problem currently, and it was solved by put my if condition in my native function. i hope this works